# Trying to make a menu that keeps repeating if the user enters something invalid

Tags: c#, menu

Total beginner here, literally started learning programming for the first time in my life yesterday, so please don't judge!

I'm trying to make a program that allows the user to enter the name and score of videogames, then show these scores upon request. I'm trying to make a menu. I noticed the program would crash if the user presses enter without entering any number, and I wanted to avoid that, but I'm stuck. If I press enter it doesn't crash. However, if I enter 1 or 2, the menu keeps going anyways, and if I press enter without entering anything after that, then it crashes? I'm lost.

```
namespace videogaems
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            menu();
        }
        static void menu()
        {
            int option = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Select what you want to do: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1- add game");
            Console.WriteLine("2- show game rating");
            bool tryAgain = true;
            while (tryAgain)
            {
                try
                {
                    while (option != 1 || option != 2)
                    {
                        option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        tryAgain = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    option = 0;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: `option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` is the problem. If it's not a number, it will crash. Do `option = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int number) ? number : 0;` This will try and parse the value, if it succeeds then `number` would get assigned that value and then assigned to `option`, otherwise `0` will be assigned.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're code seems to throw an exception on `option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` try to debug it and see what kind of exception you are seeing. you can do that by assigning a variable to the exception like `catch (Exception ex)` and see what's inside `ex`. google for that exception and you'll find your answer

Comment: The logical condition of your while loop is wrong. It should enter the loop if option is not 1 and not  2. So it should be _while (option != 1 && option != 2)_

Comment: In any case you shouldn't use an exception to drive your code. Particularly when there is the possibility to avoid it. Int32.TryParse is the way to go when you want to convert user input to an integer

Comment: @Bizhan that works and makes the exception handling redundant, thanks

Comment: @Steve Oh my god, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` will throw an exception if the string cannot be converted to an integer. Instead, you should use `int.TryParse`, which takes in a `string` and an `out` parameter that gets set to the converted value (if successful). It returns a `bool` which indicates if it was successful or not.

For example, the following code will loop as long as `int.TryParse` fails, and when it succeeds, `userInput` will contain the converted number:

```
int userInput;

while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number");
}
```

---

Another option, however, is to simply use `Console.ReadKey()`, which returns a `ConsoleKeyInfo` object that represents the key that the user pressed. Then we can just check the value of the key character (and ignore any keys that are invalid).

For example:

```
static void Menu()
{
    bool exit = false;

    while (!exit)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Select what you want to do: ");
        Console.WriteLine("  1: Add a game");
        Console.WriteLine("  2: Show game rating");
        Console.WriteLine("  3: Exit");

        ConsoleKeyInfo userInput = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();

        switch (userInput.KeyChar)
        {
            case '1':
                // Code to add a game goes here (call AddGame() method, for example)
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Add a game was selected");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to return to menu");
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;
            case '2':
                // Code to show a game rating goes here (call ShowRating(), for example)
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Show game rating was selected");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to return to menu");
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;
            case '3':
                // Exit the menu
                exit = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```